# Apache JMeter: "Test Script Recorder" - Patterns to include / exclude not actual

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter application, it seems that my settings for black- and whitelisting of patterns isn't always up-to-date when I start the recording. E.g. I get .gif files back in my recordings list, although i set it in my exclude (blacklist) settings with .*.gif

Also the suggested excludes won't influence the recording.

**edit**

The problem seem not to be the regexes, but the setting itself. It seems that they aren't always actual. E.g. if I set the default backlist-values via the "suggested excludes" button, the values aren't filtered out in the next recording. It seems to update the black/ whitelist settings not always automatically. Could this be and how can I force the use of the changed lists?

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern for excluding .gif files should look like `.*\.(gif)` as URL Patterns to Include/Exclude" inputs expect [PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)](http://www.pcre.org/)

See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of the JMeter's User Manual for additional information on regular expressions and [JMeter's Superpower: The HTTP Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) for some real-life examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem seem not to be the regexes, but the setting itself. It seems that they aren't always actual. E.g. if I set the default backlist-values via the "suggested excludes" button, the values aren't filtered out in the next recording. It seems to update the black/ whitelist settings not always automatically. Could this be and how can I force the use of the changed lists??